# Typescript: Reference Generic Type from within a value to use as a type elsewhere

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Have following code:

```js
// file1.ts
interface X { ... } // Don't want to directly export this (private/internal)

// Assume LibInterface<T> is some random interface from an external library
export const func: (arg: LibInterface<X> => string) = ...;


// file2.ts (essentially the jest test file)
import { func } from './file1';

const x: X = ...;
const arg: LibInterface<X> = ...;

expect(func(arg)).toEqual(...);
```

In the above, how do I reference the type `X` in the 2nd file?

Complex use-case using the type `X` and `jest-mock-extended`: `const mockX = mock<X>(...);`

I've searched for this as well as looked through https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.htmlhttps://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html, but find a solution.

Comment: current workaround: copy the declaration of `X` into the test file and use that. Compiler does not show errors since all fields match. This adds a small maintenance overhead

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to add a generic type to the function? Would be something like:

```
// file1.ts
interface X { ... } // Don't want to directly export this (private/internal)

// Assume LibInterface<T> is some random interface from an external library
export const func: <T extends X = X>(arg: LibInterface<T> => string) = ...;


// file2.ts (essentially the jest test file)
import { func } from './file1';

const x: X = ...;
const arg: LibInterface<X> = ...;

expect(func(arg)).toEqual(...);
```

Comment: I get what you are trying to do. This way I can define my own test interface which has all fields of `X` and use that, though if I'm doing that I may as well duplicate the whole interface in the test file. (Added comment to main question)